# Multiple arguments in IF statement?

Tags: excel

I have a column of values where I need to determine if `column A = Y, A = 7, or if A = 0.9-1`.

I tried this IFS statement, but am getting stuck on the number range piece (>1 and <7 and also <.9)

`=IFS(a2="Y","Pass",a2=7,"Pass",a2=`

any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered the logical `AND` and `OR` functions?

Comment: `=IF(OR(A2={"Y",7},AND(A2>=0.9,A2<=1),"PASS","FAIL")`